# Adding a delegate to OData model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, delegation

I'm trying to learn OData (.Net Core) and I've seen examples of how to create a model here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/model-builder-untyped

I want to create an OData action which is bound to an entity and supposed to receive an `Action<SomeComplexType>` as a parameter to the action.

Is it possible? If so, will it behave like a normal callback and know how to use the sender's state in the callback?

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? (i.e. why do you need an Action as a parameter)

Comment: AFAIK an OData object is nothing more than a simple DTO. It just holds some values (maybe complex,nested, but at the end just values) which can be serialized/deserialized. Acting on these values (on sending/receiving) is a different job and should be done by some kind of container or similar and that could have Actions, Funcs, Events, etc. that will be fired according to your business rules.

Comment: @Oliver can you show an example how to pass such object which can be serialized and de serialized to an action or events?

Comment: When you define an action on the model, you also define the return type. Everything between the request and the response is up to you and your custom implementation, its up to your code to produce the _state_ of the call back

Comment: You'll need to include an example method implementation of your action, from that we can help you identify how to declare it in the Edm Model.